# Inverse Fourier transform of a specific function

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-transform

Is there an explicit formula for the inverse Fourier transfrom of the following function
$$f(\xi)=\frac{1}{(1+\xi^2)^\alpha}\,,$$
where $\xi\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\alpha>1$?

Comment: For integer values of $\alpha$ it is given by a multiple convolution, but for $\alpha=\frac{3}{2}$ and similar values modified Bessel functions of the second kind are involved.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio can you suggest me some references about this? Thanks

Comment: CAS says: $\mathcal{F}_{\omega }^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{\left(1+\omega ^2\right)^{\alpha }}\right](x)=\frac{2^{\frac{1}{2}-\alpha } \left| x\right|
   ^{-\frac{1}{2}+\alpha } K_{\frac{1}{2}-\alpha }(\left| x\right| )}{\sqrt{\pi } \Gamma (\alpha )}$ where $K_{\frac{1}{2}-\alpha }(\left| x\right| )$ is modified Bessel function of the second kind.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Could you please tell me what CAS is? And where I can find this formula?

Comment: @MohammadJavadVaez `CAS` like Mathematica. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Thanks a lot 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an integral representation that shows the inverse transform to be a positive function. A derivation starts with the gamma function:
\begin{align}
        \Gamma(\alpha)&=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t}t^{-1+\alpha}dt,\;\; \Re\alpha > 0.
\\
         \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-st}t^{-1+\alpha}dt&=s^{-\alpha}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-st}(st)^{-1+\alpha}d(st)=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha)}{s^{\alpha}}.
\\
     \frac{1}{(1+\xi^2)^{\alpha}} &= \frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-(1+\xi^2)t}t^{-1+\alpha}dt
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}
     f^{\vee}(x) & = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{i\xi x}}{(1+\xi^2)^{\alpha}}d\xi \\
 &=\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{-1+\alpha}e^{-t}
  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-t\xi^2}e^{i\xi x}ds dt \\
   &= \frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{-1+\alpha}e^{-t}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2t}}e^{-x^2/4t}dt \\
 &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\Gamma(\alpha)}\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{-3/2+\alpha}e^{-t}e^{-x^2/4t}dt.
\end{align}

Comment: Isn't there any more known representation? Like the one for inverse Laplace transform? http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/auxiliary/inttrans/LapInv4.pdf